# Contraseña se vuelve a encriptar al hacer update

Tags: php, crud

Estoy haciendo una tabla de usuarios con operaciones CRUD. Inserto usuarios con la contraseña encriptada en MD5, hasta ahí todo bien, pero tengo problemas en la operación de modificar ya que cuando actualiza los demás campos vuelve a encriptar la contraseña de nuevo, por lo que se pierde la contraseña de ese usuario. Se que las condiciones no están bien, pero no he conseguido dar con la solución.

```
if($_POST['action_type'] == 'edit'){
        $msg = '';
        $status = $verr = 0;

    if(!empty($_POST['id'])){
        // Insert data in the database

        foreach ($nombrecolumnas as $value)
        {           
            if($value == 'password'){
                if($userData[$value] != md5($_POST['password'])){
                    $userData [$value] = md5($_POST['password']);
                }
            }else{
                $userData [$value] = $_POST[$value];
            }

            $condition = array('id' => $_POST['id']);
            $update = $db->update($tblName, $userData, $condition);
```

Comment: Puedes explicar bien que es lo que quieres hacer o tu problema porque lo que veo es que validas lo que tienes en $userData con lo que viene en $_POST si no son iguales actualizas el password

Comment: prueba a declarar el resultado del md5 en una variable. `$encripted = md5($_POST['password'])` y hacer la comparacion y asignacion con tu variable

Comment: Basicamente lo que ocurre es que introduzco un usuario con la contraseña encriptada, pero al modificar cualquier otro dato del usuario la contraseña vuelve a encriptar la encriptacion de antes. La tabla recoge los datos en tiempo real de la base de datos, por eso mi pensamiento de comparar la contraseña de la base de datos con la nueva introducida